# SQL Server : record filter on two column with interchangeable values

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with following data:

```
pkId      FromUserId         ToUserID     Message
----------------------------------------------------------------
1         100                101          Hello 101
2         101                100          Hi 101
3         102                100          hello 100 from Me,102
```

I want to get only one record from table whose `FromUserId` is not equal to `ToUserID` and `ToUserID` is not equal to `FromUserId` of other rows with others rows, like:

```
pkId      FromUserId         ToUserID     Message
----------------------------------------------------------------
2         101                100          Hi 101
3         102                100          hello 100 from Me,102
```

How it could be achieved in SQL Server?

Comment: please show us what you have done so far to try to solve this and then we can highlight what you are doing wrong and advise you in a way that isn't simply giving you an answer. if we can correct the problems with your code and explain them you are more likely to learn something from posting this question.

Comment: I'm actually working on already developed database table and its relation. And table relation is quite complex and cannot chage the table design.
this is just a simplified structure I've shown with the expected output

Comment: I didn't ask you to change the table design, I asked you to show us your efforts of trying to solve this problem.

Comment: I didn't get any idea of achiving it. I'm, at my office, tried with orignal table with many ways but didn't succed

Comment: Basically I'v a inbox like table, in which Messages are stored betweenn user, basic column are id, message, fromuserid, touserid. I've to list unique communication between user. Like A send message, Hello B, to B then B send Hello to a, as well as A send Message To c, As there are only two unique communication one is between a and b and another is between a and c. I just want to list only two

Comment: `ToUserID is not equal to FromUserId of other rows with others rows`, kill me but I've read 10 times but didn't undestand what you mean.

Comment: read above comment  Giorgi

Answer (score 0):

First declare a variable table (not a temporary table)

```
DECLARE @table table(
    id INT NOT NULL,
    from VARCHAR(100),
    to VARCHAR(100)
);
```

Then add only the id of the rows that you want to that table

```
INSERT INTO @table
    SELECT pkId, FromUserId, ToUserID
    FROM TABLE1 
    WHERE FromUserId <> ToUserID
    GROUP BY pkId, FromUserId, ToUserID
```

Then select your results

```
SELECT t1.pkId, t1.FromUserId, t1.ToUserID, t1.Messagge
FROM TABLE1 t1
INNER JOIN @table t0
ON t1.pkId = t0.id
```

Comment: I want only unique communition between user, I'm not caring about message right now

Comment: I know, but I've tested in sql server 2000, and when you use the `group by` statement you must match the columns of the gorup with the columns you are selecting.

Comment: but what if messages have the same value

Comment: can I do this with cursor or temp table

Comment: I think a variable table is best than a temp table. You can declare a `@table` with the `pkId` of the row you want using the query of my answer, and then just select all the rows from your original table where the id is in `@table`

Comment: Not showing all record and by the way t2, t3 are t1?

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from table2 where pkid in
(
select MAX(pkid) from table2 where (fromuserid in (select touserid from
[table2]) and touserid in (select fromuserid from [table2]))
)
or pkid in
(
select pkid from table2 where (fromuserid not in (select touserid from
[table2]) or touserid not in (select fromuserid from [table2]))
)
```

Answer (score -2):

```
select * from table1 where fromuserid not in
(select touserid from table1)
and 
touserid not in
(select fromuserid from table1)

select * from [123] where ToUserID = 100
```

Comment: That wouldn't return any row

Comment: Yes, It's not returning any row at all

Comment: Oh I had put fruserid instead of fromuserid, I edited it, it should work now.

Comment: insted it is not returning any row

Comment: I think I might have misunderstood the question. The code above compares each touserid with all fromuserids and then compares each fromuserid with all touserids and only outputs rows whose touserid never appears in the fromuserid column and whose fromuserid never appears in the touserid column. Is this the effect you were looking for?

Comment: Basically I'v a inbox like table, in which Messages are stored betweenn user, basic column are id, message, fromuserid, touserid. I've to list unique communication between user.
Like  A send message, Hello B, to B then B send Hello to a, as well as A send Message To c, As there are only two unique communication  one is between a and b and another is between a and c. I just want to list only two

Comment: So the times when there was a communication but no answer.

Comment: How are you deciding between the call from 101 to 100 and the call from 100 back to 101? i.e. which one to show?

Comment: any one record having larger id